# Scala IDE error - "projectname" is not a Scala project -

Tags: scala, ide, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

I have installed latest scala ide plugin to eclipse (Version: 3.4.2). It seems installation is ok without any errors.

I am able to create a scala project and add a package, but i couldn't add scala object, at the time it shows **"projectname" is not a Scala project** error message in add object dialog.

I have googled and found it could be related to JDT Weaving not enabled in eclipse. I have verified, its enabled and running in my environment.

Below the screenshot of the error. 
[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img80/3070/scala.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img80/3070/scala.png)

I just started scala.. Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Scala projects should show `S` in the top right corner of the folder icon, and not `J`. Try right-clicking on it; is there a "Scala" sub-menu in the context menu? If so, what items are there? In particular, if there is an item "Add Scala nature", add it and check if you can create a Scala class then.

Comment: ...and it is worth to mention that scala sub-menu is visible in the Scala perspective (at least in my installation, in Java perspective I don't have "Add scala nature" option).

Comment: In my build (Eclipse Kepler Java EE) "Add scala nature" was under "Configure"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message means your project is not recognize as a Scala one (as detailed in the [`scala.tools.eclipse.wizards.AbstractNewElementWizardPage.scala`](http://www.assembla.com/code/scala-ide/git/nodes/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/src/scala/tools/eclipse/wizards/AbstractNewElementWizardPage.scala?rev=b7f1f2b0012b3d533fbb81348d03c04aa54d71fa) class.
But adding "Scala nature" to your project, as suggested by [Alexey Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov) in the comments, might not be enough in this case.

The requirements mentioned in **[scala-ide.org](http://www.scala-ide.org/)** clearly include:

- [Java Developer Toolkit 1.6](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/)
- [Eclipse Classic 3.5.2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/galileo/sr2)

So could you try with a more recent Eclipse version?
See [Requirements and Installation](https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Requirements_and_Installation), and then [the turorial](https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Tutorial_Example):

[image]

As mentioned, note the '`S`' in the Scala project icon.

Comment: Hi Vonc, i have installed the scala plugin for eclipse galileo in my VM.... it works great without any problems... but earlier i installed in eclipse galileo ganymede...

Comment: @Ramesh: "in eclipse galileo ganymede"? I don't recall of such an eclipse. Eclipse Ganymede is 3.4.x, Eclipse Galileo is 3.5.x, but there is no such think as an "eclipse galileo ganymede".

Comment: thats a typo :(.. i mean eclipse galileo

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar error two minutes ago. Here's how I fixed it. I'm using Helios and the relevant Scala IDE version.

> Right click on the project name --> Configure --> Add scala nature

I must mention that I have the M2Eclipse plugin as well and my project is a Maven project in addition to having a Scala "nature" .. Not that it should matter .. ;-)

Comment: I've imported maven scala project into the most recent eclipse ide with scala ide installed and your answer was the only one allowing me to add scala classes from IDE without this annoying error... thanks!